# Checking Boxes in DataGridRows that are in another List

Tags: c#, wpf, datagrid

I have a `DataGrid` that has an `ObservableCollection` of type `Tennant` (excuse the spelling please, I'll fix it eventually) as its `ItemsSource`. The `Tennant` class is made up of a Name, Email, Phone number, and Occupation. In the DataGrid however, I have a group of all of the Tennants in the program with only their name,  a check box to show whether they live or have ever lived in the current `Property` being edited, and also a Radio Button that shows whether it is the current `Tennant` of the `Property`. Here is a screen shot:

[image: Editing Property Window]

My problem is at the Lived Here column. That isn't bound to any part of the `Tennant` or `Property` classes. It instead has two events (Checked and Unchecked) that essentially add it to the Current Property. Here's one of them. The other one is pretty much identical except it's remove instead of add. (Plus I made my own `DataGridColumnTemplate` because the CheckBox one doesn't have those events...)

```
private void livedHereCheck_Checked(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    CheckBox chkd = (sender as CheckBox);
    Tennant cur = (chkd.DataContext as Tennant);
    CurrentProperty.addTennant(cur);
}
```

So that works (although there is most definitely a better way of doing that I'm quite sure). The real problem arises when I first open the window, I need to set some of the lived here CheckBoxes to be set already because they're already in the `CurrentProperty.tennants` Property (excuse the fact that it's lowercase. Still getting the hang of wpf and c# standards etc.)

Currently I have this:

```
private void Window_Initialized(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    var iSource = tennantsGrid.ItemsSource;
    foreach (Tennant cur in iSource)
    {
        var row = tennantsGrid.ItemContainerGenerator.ContainerFromItem(cur);
        if (row != null)
        {
            if (CurrentProperty.hasTennant(cur))
            {
                // Something here... Not sure yet how to actually check the box but that goes here.
            }  
        }
    }
}
```

So that's what I need help with. How do I do that on window initialize or is it better to do it somewhere else to avoid confusion? Is there a better way of doing everything I'm trying? Do you need any more code to help answer? Thank you!

Comment: Did you try IValueConverter for the same? I think `IMultiValueConverter` will work for you in this scenario.

Comment: @PushprajRuhal Where are you talking about this? And how?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So we will be doing it more WPF approach

Start with defining a converter class

```
class HasTennantConverter : IMultiValueConverter
{
    public object Convert(object[] values, Type targetType, object parameter, System.Globalization.CultureInfo culture)
    {
        Tennant tennant = values[0] as Tennant;
        Property property = values[1] as Property;
        return property.hasTennant(tennant);
    }

    public object[] ConvertBack(object value, Type[] targetTypes, object parameter, System.Globalization.CultureInfo culture)
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }
}
```

then in your XAML add this converter to your resources

```
<l:HasTennantConverter x:Key="HasTennantConverter"/>
```

and this binding to your CheckBox in the row Style or Template

I've used Window as my relative source to retrieve the CurrentProperty, you may choose appropriate binding to retrieve the same.

```
<CheckBox>
    <CheckBox.IsChecked>
        <MultiBinding Converter="{StaticResource HasTennantConverter}" Mode="OneWay">
            <Binding />
            <Binding Path="DataContext.CurrentProperty" RelativeSource="{RelativeSource Mode=FindAncestor, AncestorType=Window}"/>
        </MultiBinding>
    </CheckBox.IsChecked>
</CheckBox>
```

this mutlibinding will send Tennant and CurrentProperty to the converter and the logic will be checked in the converter and will return true or false based on your logic which will either check or uncheck the CheckBox.

Comment: You were absolutely correct. It didn't work at first, but that was just because the .Equals() method for Property was testing with the default method. I just overrode it and not it works great! Thanks.